# Complexity analysis - adding 2 functions

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I have a homework question asks

```
Given f(n) is O(k(n)) and g(n) is O(k(n)), prove f(n)+g(n) is also O(k(n))
```

I'm not sure where to start with this, any help to guide me of how to work on this?

Comment: Straight from the definition of big O, I would say. What have you tried?

Comment: read my answer on the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11137859/1321404

Answer (score 0):

Try and work through it logically.  `f(n)` increases at a linear rate.  So does `g(n)`.    Therefore

```
O(n) + O(n) = O(2n)
```

When attempting to find the big O classification of a function, constants don't count.
I'll leave the rest (including the *why*) as an exercise for you.  (Getting the full answer on SO would be cheating!)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [**Rules for Big-Oh Notation.**](http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/csc210/exhibit/chap04/bigOhRules.html)

**Sum Rule:** If `f(n)` is `O(h(n))` and `g(n)` is `O(p(n))`, then `f(n)+g(n)` is `O(h(n)+p(n))`.

Using this rule for your case the complexity would be `O(2k(n))`, which is nothing but `O(k(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

So, f(n) is O(g(n)) iff f(n) is less than or equal to some positive constant multiple of g(n) for arbitrarily large values of n (so this: f(n) <= cg(n) for n >= n_0). Usually, to prove something is O(g(n)), we provide some c and n_0 to show that it is true.

In your case, I would start by using that definition, so you could say f(n) <= ck(n) and g(n) <= dk(n). I don't want to totally answer the question for you, but you are basically just going to try to show that f(n)+g(n) <= tk(n).

*c, d, and t are all just arbitrary, positive constants. If you need more help, just comment, and I will gladly provide more info.